Cloud Native Buildpacks for JDK 21
pack builder suggest reutrns
Google: gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1
Heroku: heroku/builder:20
Heroku: heroku/builder:22
Paketo Buildpacks: paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base
Paketo Buildpacks: paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-buildpackless-static
Paketo Buildpacks: paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-full
Paketo Buildpacks: paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-tiny

I tried the 2 heroku builders, the google builder and jammy-base builder
and the error message i got was
  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project hubjet: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 21 not supported -> [Help 1]
  [ERROR]
  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
  [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
  [ERROR]
  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
  [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

So I am assuming JDK 21 is not supported and they are expecting JDK 17.
What command do I run to set the JDK version of the buildpack for 21?
I tried with
pack build test-img --builder paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-buildpackless-static --buildpack paketo-buildpacks/java

but it didnt work.
Where can I even browse all available paketobuildpacks for the JDK ? For an example what are the names of all avaialbe buildpacks for --buildpack command

inspect should show you the available buildpacks, but at least in my case is not sowing any.
pack inspect paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base
...
Buildpacks:
  (buildpack metadata not present)
...

You can find the available buildpacks here.
For paketo-buildpacks/java the one that provides the JDK version is paketo-buildpacks/bellsoft-liberica.
There you can see that $BP_JVM_VERSION is available for you to set.
pack build test-img --builder paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base --env BP_JVM_VERSION=21


The full list of Paketo provided JVM vendors is here -> https://paketo.io/docs/howto/java/#use-an-alternative-jvm. If you click through to the buildpack's README, and look at the BP_JVM_VERSION setting you can see the list of Java versions we support for that vendor. Most have 21 support, but not all yet.
